# build vnc4server from source

Tags: vnc, tinycore

I want to build vnc4server from source, but am surprized that I'm unable to find the source code.

Background:

- I'm running TinyCore linux for a few years on a 32bit embedded
  devices. It's running vnc4server for remote access.
- The 32bit embedded devices are not available anymore, so for new projects we're looking at a switch to 64bit devices. I'm setting up
  TinyCore in as much the same setup as the old devices. But now
  vnc4server is not available as an app for TinyCore 64bit. I've had other
  such apps (atftpd, bftpd, ...) which I just built from source.

However I can't find the source for vnc4server. It seems to be part of ubuntu. It seems to be based on realVnc, of which I can't find the source as well.

Any ideas where to look?
Or any ideas for the closest alternative vnc server?

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/vnc4server on the right side there are links to the source code, ubuntu adaptions and checksums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vnc4server is indeed from RealVNC, as mentioned in the manpage. It was packaged for Debian [in 2004 by Ola Lundqvist](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/v/vnc4/vnc4_4.1.1+X4.3.0+t-1_copyright), and that's how it reaches Ubuntu. The last version packaged for Debian was [4.1.1 in Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/vnc4server) (with patches), after which it was replaced with [TigerVNC in Stretch](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/vnc4server).

You can download the 4.1.3 version sources from [RealVNC's archive page](https://archive.realvnc.com/download/open/). You can also get [Debian's sources for Jessie](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/vnc4server) (look for links to source package in the sidebar).

But, like Debian did, you might want to switch to TigerVNC instead. I don't think RealVNC have done any development for vnc4 since 2005 (going by timestamps in the archive).